# Why spark application are not running on all nodes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, benchmarking

I installed the following spark benchmark:
https://github.com/BBVA/spark-benchmarks
I run Spark on top of YARN on 8 workers but I only get 2 running executors during the job (TestDFSIO). 
I also set `executor-cores` to be 9 but only 2 are running.
Why would that happen?

I think the problem is coming from YARN because I get a similar (almost) issue with TestDFSIO on Hadoop. In fact, at the beginning of the job, only two nodes run, but then all the nodes execute the application in parallel!

Note that I am not using HDFS for storage!

Comment: How can you run TestDFSIO without HDFS?

Comment: I use another file system

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. What I've done is that I set the number of cores per executor to 5 (`--executor-cores`) and the total number of executors to 23 (`--num-executors`) which was at first 2 by default.